# HTTP request tracker on Iphone and XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am able to track HTTP Requests on a simulator because I have access to a terminal. How could I track requests on an Iphone?

Comment: Can you clarify? You mean run analytics? There are analytics services out there (free and paid). Additionally some of the crash tracking services also can track network calls. Or you can roll your own.

Comment: @Mobile Ben Thank you, Basically I need to know the HTTP Get  requests made by my app